# SQL mariaDB trigger on column update

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I have a 1st table having columns as id, name and status and 2nd table columns as id and status.

Whenever there is any update on 1st table, status column for a specific id column , i want to update the 2nd table's column status value as 1st table status value.

1st table id column = 2nd table id column

Comment: Sounds like a simple update to the other table for the specified ID ... what is the issue?

Comment: can you please give me the trigger details to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would create this trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_status
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE table2 
    SET status = NEW.status
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END
```

This is for the `UPDATE` only. You probably have to create another trigger which inserts new rows from `table1` in `table2`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_status
    AFTER INSERT
    ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 (id, status)
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.status);
END
```